# Handling FileNotFoundException with try-catch

Tags: java

```
static boolean exists(String location) {
        File path = new File(location);
        if (path.exists()){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

static boolean checkFile(String location1) throws IOException {
        if ( exists(location1) ) {
            File file = new File(location1);
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            raf.seek( raf.length()-1 );
            byte lastByte = raf.readByte();
            raf.close();
            if (lastByte == 2) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File does not exist, please try again: ");
            Scanner sk = new Scanner(System.in);
            String newLocation = sk.nextLine();
            checkFile(newLocation);
            sk.close();
            return false;
```

With that said, I have checked with a separate method whether a file even exists, however, I would like to now compress the above into a single method by somehow recursively utilizing the try-catch:

```
static boolean checkFile(String location) {

        try {
            File file = new File(location);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist, please try again: ");
            Scanner sk = new Scanner(System.in);
            String newLocation = sk.nextLine();
            checkFile(newLocation);
        }

        //the following if-sentence checking whether some byte checks up.
    }
```

1st problem: how can I create a new random access file using the `File file` inside try? I did try initializing it before try `File file = null;` , but then it throws NullPointer, because after it catches the exception, the method is called again and the file will automatically be null.

Another idea was to `try-catch` inside a `do-while`-loop , but then I was thinking about do while what? I would have to check whether the file exists, considering that's what I'm already doing with `try-catch` it becomes redundant.

What can I do to `try-catch` as long as I input a path that is not a file and  then proceed with the `if` sentence all in one method?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use try-catch?  This problem is much easier without it.

Comment: Yes, it is specifically stated to use try-catch for this problem, though, I myself, too, find this a bit odd, because wouldn't it be easier to have a method that checks for file existence when we have n methods that all do different things with files?

Comment: not anything about the "answer" but I just can't let it go:  Consider condensing the "if/else" in `exists` to be `return (new File(location)).exists();`

Comment: Oh, thanks for the suggestion, that looks a lot neater.

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use `try/catch`, which I really don't recommend, you could do it in a "forever" loop, something like this.

```
public static FileReader readerForPromptedFile() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a file name");
            String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
            return new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found, please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
static boolean checkFile(String location) {

    while (!exists(location)){
        System.out.println("File does not exist, please try again: ");
        Scanner sk = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newLocation = sk.nextLine();         
    }

    try {
    //the following if-sentence checking whether some byte checks up.
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

It's generally frowned on to use a method which could throw an exception if there is a reasonable way to check whether it should work first - in that case the behaviour isn't really an exception, it's more of a precondition.  It also adds quite a large performance overhead.